# Ability to navigate back with browser button without showing control alerts message boxs that appearing in the middle of the navigation process

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I am searching for techniques/ approaches to solve this problem:

dummy scenário:

In main page I have a button. when I click on it, it display a message: "are you sure?"
when I click ok... it redirect me for secondary page. Now if I want to go back, I click in back button of the browser... my intended behavior is to the application go to main page... but instead it show  the alert box "are you sure"...
the same appens in forms...when I click back the application keep point me to the previous input instead of go to the previous page.

I suppose that is a dummy question... but for this context I don't have the knowledge for "googling" the right Keywords... so point me in the right direction it will be a huge Help;)

Comment: Do you have search for pagination?

Comment: Hi, I did not. I follow your advise. but all I found is about paging gridviews. My intended is to be able to navigate around different pages and when I go back, the application show me the previous page, not the message box that appear in the "changing page event".

ACTUAL scenario:(-->):page1-->messagebox-->page2;(<--): page2<--messageBox<--page1. 

IDEAL scenario(-->): page1-->messagebox-->page2;(<--): page2<--page1.